# JOptionsPane Input Dialog

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to create an input box which takes responses from the user. I've noticed that eclipse has given me 2 extra arguments after the icon argument (text, answer), and I'm not sure what is supposed to go in them.

```
String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Give us a word starting with "+text[i]+":", "ABCTutor", 0, image, text, answer);
```

Comment: Read the javadoc + try it out. It won't send your passwords to Chinese hackers if you get it wrong, trust me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into [Java's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29).

```
selectionValues - an array of Objects that gives the possible selections
initialSelectionValue - the value used to initialize the input field
```

An example:

```
Object[] options = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null,
    "Click OK to continue", 
    "Warning",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
    null,
    options,  // available options
    options[0]); // default option
```

Comment: `selectionValues` are values that the user can select one of them.

Comment: ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!